# Подсчет количества слайдов в карусели

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, карусель

Здравствуйте! Есть слайдер - [SliderPro](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro). Использую его в своем проекте, сейчас стал вопрос - как сделать подсчет количества слайдов в карусели в формате `1/n` где `1` - номер текущего слайда, `n` - их суммарное количество. В API слайдера я виду методы, которые вроде бы позволяют реализовывать такую штуку: `getSelectedSlide()`, `getTotalSlides()` ([ссылка](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#gettotalslides)), но как их использовать я не знаю. Просьба помочь. [Линк на кодпен с примером](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/ZBZeJd).

P.S. Карусель зациклена, так что подсчет слайдов `html` проблему не решит (слайды клонируются)

```js
var $sliderEl = $('#my-slider');
var sliderObj;

setTimeout(function () {
    $sliderEl.sliderPro({
        width: 698,
        height: 561,
        imageScaleMode: 'contain',
        buttons: false,
        arrows: true,
        fadeArrows: false,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: false,
        slideAnimationDuration: 1000,

        thumbnailPointer: true,
        thumbnailsPosition: 'right',
        thumbnailWidth: 336,
        thumbnailHeight: 115,
        breakpoints: {
            1366: {
                width: 484
            },
            1023: {
                thumbnailPointer: false
            }
        }
    });
    sliderObj = $sliderEl.data( 'sliderPro' );
}, 400);

$('.fullscreen-slider-btn').click(function() {
    if ('undefined' !== sliderObj) {
        sliderObj.update();
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/slider-pro.min_.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://freepps.top/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
    <div class="sp-slides">
        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 2 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 3 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image3_medium.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере не вижу, чтобы слайды клонировались. Всё те же три блока с классом `.sp-slide`, к которым по кругу добавляется класс `.sp-selected`.

Если ничего не напутал, то достаточно пересчитать слайды и найти индекс активного слайда.

Обновлять счётчик удобно [по событию `gotoSlideComplete`](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#gotoslidecomplete). А задать ему первое значение – [по событию `init`](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#init).

Проверьте: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/MbRomQ

```js
var $sliderEl = $('#my-slider');
var sliderObj;

setTimeout(function () {
  $sliderEl.sliderPro({
    width: 698,
    height: 561,
    imageScaleMode: 'contain',
    buttons: false,
    arrows: true,
    fadeArrows: false,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    slideAnimationDuration: 1000,

    thumbnailPointer: true,
    thumbnailsPosition: 'right',
    thumbnailWidth: 336,
    thumbnailHeight: 115,
    breakpoints: {
      1366: {
        width: 484
      },
      1023: {
        thumbnailPointer: false
      }
    }
  });
  sliderObj = $sliderEl.data( 'sliderPro' );
}, 400);
$('.fullscreen-slider-btn').click(function() {
  if ('undefined' !== sliderObj) {
    sliderObj.update();
  }
});

var $counter = $('#slide-counter');
$sliderEl.on( 'init', updateCounter )
$sliderEl.on( 'gotoSlideComplete', updateCounter )

function updateCounter() {
  $counter.text( ($sliderEl.find('.sp-selected').index() + 1) + ' / ' +  $sliderEl.find('.sp-slide').length );
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slider-pro/1.6.0/css/slider-pro.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slider-pro/1.6.0/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
  
<h1 id="slide-counter">Номер слайда</h1>

<div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
    <div class="sp-slides">
        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300/369/9cf?text=1"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 2 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300/936/f9c?text=2"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Slide 3 -->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300/693/cf9?text=3"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPD**. Рядом был ответ как использовать методы `getSelectedSlide()` и `getTotalSlides()`, но автор его удалил. А дело в том, что для этого оставался один шаг – применить их к `sliderObj`.

Но применять их следует только после инициализации слайдера, иначе `sliderObj` окажется `undefined`. Т. е., блоки в DOM можно пересчитать и по событию `init`, а обращаться к `sliderObj` по этому событию ещё рано.

Поэтому последовательность шагов получается другая:

1. Инициализировать слайдер (и здесь же повесить обновление счётчика на событие `gotoSlideComplete`).
2. Получить указатель на экземпляр слайдера.
3. Обновить счётчик слайдов, чтобы показать его начальное значение.

Такая цепочка действий работает и для моего решения. Вот пример с двумя решениями сразу. Слева считаем блоки в дереве элементов, справа — используем `getSelectedSlide()` и `getTotalSlides()`. Для наглядности убрал `Timeout` и часть настроек слайдера.

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/zoXVdL

```js
var $counter1 = $('#counter1');
var $counter2 = $('#counter2');
var $sliderEl = $('#my-slider');

/* 1. */
$sliderEl.sliderPro({
  width: 808,
  height: 400,
  imageScaleMode: 'cover',
  arrows: true,
  fadeArrows: false,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  gotoSlideComplete: updateCounter
});

/* 2. */
var sliderObj = $sliderEl.data( 'sliderPro' );

/* 3. */
updateCounter();

function updateCounter() {
  $counter1.text( ($sliderEl.find('.sp-selected').index() + 1) + ' / ' +  $sliderEl.find('.sp-slide').length ); 
  $counter2.text( (sliderObj ? ((sliderObj.getSelectedSlide() + 1) + ' / ' + sliderObj.getTotalSlides()) : '...') );
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.counter { margin-bottom: 12px; }
.counter_left  { float: left; }
.counter_right { float: right; text-align: right; }
.counter__about {
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
}
.counter__value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.slider-pro {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="counter counter_left">
    <div class="counter__value" id="counter1">Slide Counter</div>
    <div class="counter__about">(index + 1) / length</div>
  </div>
  <div class="counter counter_right">
    <div class="counter__value" id="counter2">Slide Counter</div>
    <div class="counter__about">(getSelectedSlide + 1) / getTotalSlides</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
    <div class="sp-slides">
      <!-- Slide 1 -->
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300/369/9cf?text=1"/>
      </div>

      <!-- Slide 2 -->
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300/936/f9c?text=2"/>
      </div>

      <!-- Slide 3 -->
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300/693/cf9?text=3"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slider-pro/1.6.0/css/slider-pro.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slider-pro/1.6.0/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Да, действительно, я посчитал что здесь как в `owl-carousel` - слайды клонируются. Все отлично, вопрос лишь в одном: как сделать, чтобы вместо текста "Номер слайда" изначально отображалось кол-во и текущий слайд?

Comment: @Игорь Обновил ответ и CodePen. Добавил обработку события `init`.

Comment: @Игорь Добавил к ответу решение через  getSelectedSlide() и getTotalSlides().

Comment: Глеб, большое вам спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

1. Уберите setTimeout обертку
2. Оберните в $( document ).ready

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function(){
         var $sliderEl = $('#my-slider');
         var sliderObj;

         $sliderEl.sliderPro({
                     width: 698,x
                     height: 561,
                     imageScaleMode: 'contain',
                     buttons: false,
                     arrows: true,
                     fadeArrows: false,
                     loop: true,
                     autoplay: false,
                     slideAnimationDuration: 1000,

                     thumbnailPointer: true,
                     thumbnailsPosition: 'right',
                     thumbnailWidth: 336,
                     thumbnailHeight: 115,
                     breakpoints: {
                         1366: {
                             width: 484
                         },
                         1023: {
                             thumbnailPointer: false
                         }
                     }
                 });
                 sliderObj = $sliderEl.data( 'sliderPro' );
                 console.log(sliderObj.getTotalSlides());

             $('.fullscreen-slider-btn').click(function() {
                 if ('undefined' !== sliderObj) {
                     sliderObj.update();
                 }
             });

           })
   ```

Comment: setTimeout убрать не могу - слайдер работает в модалке, из-за изначального `display: none;` слайдер некорректно срабатывает..

Comment: @Игорь Значит инициализацию слайдера вынесите в функцию и вызывайте ее 
при открытии модального окна